# Python update multiple columns with where condition. Error cannot be broadcast together

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, where-clause

I need to update several columns in DB based on conditions. I am using numpy.where and would prefer to do not change that.

Here is what I could do:

```
DB['Start'] = np.where(((DB['Start Date']<=time_delta) | (DB['Start Date'].isnull()) | (DB['Start Date'] == "")),DB['Start'],DB['Start Date'])

DB['End'] = np.where(((DB['Start Date']<=time_delta) | (DB['Start Date'].isnull()) | (DB['Start Date'] == "")),DB['End'],DB['End Date'])
```

and so on for other 5 columns.. but this would not be computationally efficient.

Would be nice to have something like this:

```
DB[['Start','End']] = np.where(((DB['Start Date']<=time_delta) | (DB['Start Date'].isnull()) | (DB['Start Date'] == "")),DB[['Start','End']],DB[['Start Date','End Date']])
```

But it is not working and gives the following error message: "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (10,2) (10,2)".

Do you have any suggestions how to efficiently update multiple column based on numpy.where conditions?

Comment: Add sample data?

Comment: Not sure if can helps, but these  are the columns of DB: TID, Start, End, M, B, TaskID, Start Date, End Date, Machine, Boards. 
For the data I just put some random data for this test. Not relevant

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is acceptable to you, since you mentioned computational efficiency and this takes the same computer time as listing the update steps manually. but in case it's helpful...

```
columns_to_filter = ['Start', 'End']

for c in columns_to_filter:
    DB[c] = np.where(((DB['Start Date']<=time_delta) | (DB['Start Date'].isnull()) | (DB['Start Date'] == "")),DB[c],DB[c + ' Date'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but I was hoping a code to optimize more. I actually have 10 column to update based on the same condition. There must be a more efficient way to deal with it...